# Multiple inheritence and generic access to one base class from the other's pointer

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

My question is: "How can I implement a generic function that handles different subclasses but accesses methods from both base classes?"

I ask you to imagine that I am using a hypothetical graphics library that is structured as follows:

```
class Shape
{

// getters and setters are here

private:
   int m_BorderColor;
   int m_FillColor;
}

class Square : public Shape
{

}

class Triangle : public Shape
{

}

class TextBox : public Shape
{

}
```

... and so on.

The library only allows derivatives of the Shape base class to be added to its hypothetical canvas. In my application I would like to have a text box in each and every shape and possibly some other attributes.

Therefore I would like to have my own base class, something like the following:

```
class MyBase
{
public:
    SetText (string text) { m_Text.Text = text; }
    // other getters and setters here

private:
    TextBox m_Text;
    int m_Id;
}
```

I can then have 'my' shapes with a text box as follows:

```
class MySquare : public Square, public MyBase
{

}
```

I can add MySquare to the canvas because it is a subclass of Shape. When the user double clicks on a MySquare (or MyTriangle etc.) I want to change the text. But I only know which shape the clicked on at run time.

The following obviously doesn't work because SetText is not a member of Shape and the pointer I receive from the library, although (for example) being to a MyTriangle, is cast to a Shape:

```
// double click handler
Shape* clicked_shape = clickEvent.GetShape();
clicked_shape->SetText("Foo");
```

I need to use a base class pointer because I don't know which shape object I am getting until run time. Therefore although the following works fine, it is not useful for me:

```
// double click handler
Shape* clicked_shape = clickEvent.GetShape()
((MyTriangle*)clicked_shape)->SetText("Foo")
```

Thank you for any insight or better patterns for this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
MyBase * base = dynamic_cast<MyBase *>(clicked_shape);
base->SetText("too");
```

You might want to check for `base` being null, if the Shape you get isn't actually one of yours.

`MyBase` needs at least one virtual function for this - the destructor would do.

Comment: dynamic_cast is a last resort. In many cases it indicates a bad design. Some time it is not easily avoidable though.

Comment: @dmitri I agree; I don't use it often. But this is exactly the type of problem it is designed for.

Comment: I tried something like this but with a static_cast. The problem is that depending on which shape it is the offset to the MyBase part is different so the SetText accessor crashes. Sorry for the question, but does dynamic_cast get around this problem?

Comment: Okay, I am off to read about and try it now! Will come back later, but in the meantime thank you!

Comment: Another thought: could your shapes have a MyBase, rather then being a MyBase (composition rather than inheritance).

Comment: Firstly the good news, dynamic_cast works like a dream! Thank you for this, I am interested why dynamic_cast is bad practice and will research this topic more.

Comment: Secondly about using composition instead of inheritance, if my shapes have MyBase as a member I can't access them generically as I get a pointer to the 'Shape' base class and don't know which shape convert it too. I can't derive MyBase from Shape because of the 'Diamond problem' - I need also to subclass from Square, Triangle etc. I can derive MyBase from Shape and MySquare from MyBase with a Square as a member. This avoids multiple inheritance and dynamic_cast but all drag, drop, resize, repaint etc. events from MySquare must be explicitly sent to Square (as it is a member, not a base class)

Answer (score 0):

Shape class is a base class hence it provides an interface that can be overridden. E.g. there could be `draw()` method which is called to draw a shape. That one would be a good candidate to be overridden in your new class with text box. For example:

```
class SquareWithText: public Square {
  void draw() {
    Square::draw(); // call base method
    ... // add text box here
}
```

There is no multiple inheritance here, which gives you a simpler solution.
If single inheritance doesn't work for you you may go for a more complex solution.

```
class ShapeWithTextBox : public Shape {
  void draw() {
     ... // add text box here
  }
}
```

Now you will write your new classes as:

```
class MySquare : public Square, public ShapeWithTextBox
{
  void draw() {
    Square::draw();
    ShapeWithTextBox::draw();
}
```

It is not necessary to derive `ShapeWithTextBox` from `Shape`. It depends on the interface of `Shape class`.

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting answer, but when I get a pointer from the doubleclick event it will be a Shape*. How can I use it to access members of ShapeWithTextBox? I can't cast it because depending which shape it is, the address of the second base class will be offset by a different amount.

Comment: Also I just noticed that your MySquare class might suffer from the 'Diamond' multiple inheritance problem as Shape is a superclass of both Square and ShapeWithTextBox

Comment: Diamond problem - welcome to multiple inheritance solution :)

Comment: :) actually I would much rather not use multiple inheritance, but I can't work a pattern which avoids duplication in each subclass.

Comment: Do you implement subclasses of Shape, e.g. Triangle or those are provided by the library?

Comment: I use the ones provided by the library without further changes.